# What would be the negative effects of installing a 32bit app into the C:\Program Files\ instead of the C:\Program Files(x86)\?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

What would be the negative effects of installing a legacy 32bit app into the *C:\Program Files* instead of the *C:\Program Files(x86)* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it matters.  You can run a 64-bit from your Desktop, an external drive, etc. the same way you can run a 32-bit app.  I think the difference is purely for organization.

Or say you are developing a 32-bit and a 64-bit version of an application, you could install both of them and run them side by side by putting them in the separate Program Files folders.

Answer (score 2):

It could cause a problem based on what your application does.

For example, if your app queries for the Program Files folder, the WOW emulation layer will return Program Files (x86).  Thus if you're trying to find things relative to where you're installed, you'll fail.

Answer (score 1):

None. I believe the two folders are there for organizational purposes only.

Answer (score 1):

None whatsoever. I do it all the time, and have never encountered any ill effects. I believe it's purely organizational.

Answer (score 0):

Probably none if the application that you want to install doesn't have a 64 bit parallel version.

If it has and you decide to install it, by default (if it is using the same folder names) it will overwrite the existing 32 bit application.