# What are the negative effects for running a 64bit .NET program from Program Files (x86)?

Tags: .net, dll, x86, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

The reverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752844/what-would-be-the-negative-effects-of-installing-a-32bit-app-into-the-c-program).

My .NET C# program sets the Platform Target as 'Any CPU', which on my 64 bit Win7 OS, means it will run as 64 bit. Even when the program is stored under Program Files (x86), it will still run as 64 bit interestingly (I checked with `IntPtr.Size == 8`).

So should I expect anything bad to happen? The program references a DLL which is also 'Any CPU', but that's all. I would rather install it to the "Program Files (x86)" folder for maintenance reasons if nothing else.

And would anything bad happen if this wasn't .NET, and just a standard C/C++ executable?

Comment: AFAIK "Program Files (x86)" is just a folder, like any other.  It's there to provide a convenient place to store 32 bit executables.